# How do I use Python's pprint module to pretty print out dictionary key value pairs nested with in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pretty-print, pprint

I would like to pretty print out each key value pair from dictionaries which are nested in a list. So here is what I am working with:

```
[{"updated_at":"2011/09/26 22:39:18 +0000","url":"http://diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html","annotations":[],"user":"name","shared":"yes","tags":"python,handler,opener,urllib2","readlater":"no","created_at":"2011/09/26 22:39:18 +0000","title":"11.7.\xc2\xa0Handling redirects","comments":[],"desc":""},{"updated_at":"2011/09/26 11:09:07 +0000","url":"http://www.polimex.net/sklep/index.php?page=Category&catid=7","annotations":[],"user":"name","shared":"yes","tags":"plastic,snap,buttons,clothing","readlater":"no","created_at":"2011/09/26 11:05:48 +0000","title":"Polimex - Plastic\xc2\xa0accessories","comments":[],"desc":""}]
```

When I do

```
from pprint import pprint

data = [{"updated_at":"2011/09/26 22:39:18 +0000","url":"http://diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html","annotations":[],"user":"name","shared":"yes","tags":"python,handler,opener,urllib2","readlater":"no","created_at":"2011/09/26 22:39:18 +0000","title":"11.7.\xc2\xa0Handling redirects","comments":[],"desc":""},{"updated_at":"2011/09/26 11:09:07 +0000","url":"http://www.polimex.net/sklep/index.php?page=Category&catid=7","annotations":[],"user":"name","shared":"yes","tags":"plastic,snap,buttons,clothing","readlater":"no","created_at":"2011/09/26 11:05:48 +0000","title":"Polimex - Plastic\xc2\xa0accessories","comments":[],"desc":""}]

pprint(data)
```

the result I get is the same as the original list but in a string

```
'[{"updated_at":"2011/09/26 22:39:18 +0000","url":"http://diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html","annotations":[],"user":"name","shared":"yes","tags":"python,handler,opener,urllib2","readlater":"no","created_at":"2011/09/26 22:39:18 +0000","title":"11.7.\xc2\xa0Handling redirects","comments":[],"desc":""},{"updated_at":"2011/09/26 11:09:07 +0000","url":"http://www.polimex.net/sklep/index.php?page=Category&catid=7","annotations":[],"user":"name","shared":"yes","tags":"plastic,snap,buttons,clothing","readlater":"no","created_at":"2011/09/26 11:05:48 +0000","title":"Polimex - Plastic\xc2\xa0accessories","comments":[],"desc":""}]'
```

**How do I make it pretty print the data to look something like this?**

```
[
    {
     "updated_at":"2011/09/26 22:39:18 +0000",
     "url":"http://diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html",
     "annotations":[],
     "user":"name",
     "shared":"yes",
     "tags":"python,handler,opener,urllib2",
     "readlater":"no",
     "created_at":"2011/09/26 22:39:18 +0000",
     "title":"11.7.\xc2\xa0Handling redirects",
     "comments":[],
     "desc":""
     },
     {
     "updated_at":"2011/09/26 11:09:07 +0000",
     "url":"http://www.polimex.net/sklep/index.php?page=Category&catid=7",
     "annotations":[],
     "user":"name",
     "shared":"yes",
     "tags":"plastic,snap,buttons,clothing",
     "readlater":"no",
     "created_at":"2011/09/26 11:05:48 +0000", 
     "title":"Polimex - Plastic\xc2\xa0accessories", 
     "comments":[],"desc":"" 
     }
]
```

Comment: I just tried this from the interactive shell (literally pasted your code, above) and got the expected result. I can't fathom how you're getting a string from pprint, since it returns None.

Comment: I messed up. I forgot that the `data` list was wrapped in quotes. I'm sorry for this mistake. When I take away the quotes it pprints like expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility comes to mind. Are you supplying a JSON string to `pprint`? If so, you should first decode it:

```
pprint(json.loads(data))
```

Comment: Marcelo, you guessed it right. The list was wrapped in a string. Thanks. I did not know about the JSON module and was going to manually write a function to strip the quotes and convert to unicode.

Answer (score 1):

It um... works right for me.  (I cut and pasted your example!)  What Python and OS are you using? And are you sure you didn't accidentally add some additional quotes somewhere?

Are you printing to the terminal?

Comment: Perhaps that was more of a comment than an answer, but whatevs.

Comment: Dave, I made a mistake. I had the list wrapped in quotes. Didn't realize. Sorry.